# Problem when starting a single node of Hadoop cluster in Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and I was going through the installation process mentioned [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/). I have installed `hadoop-1.2.1` on my system. After configuring everything when I tried to start a single node cluster I got the following error:

```
$ /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/start-all.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out
/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 137: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 147: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 148: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 137: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 147: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 148: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 137: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 147: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 148: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out
/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 137: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 147: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 148: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 137: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 147: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 148: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-asad-HP-15-Notebook-PC.out: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing to run this command as root.That's why i was getting that error.Now works fine after prepending `sudo` before the command, ie:

```
sudo /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/start-all.sh
```